# Can not load HTML String in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, uiwebview

I am trying to show a HTML String in uiwebview and it give me the error below:

```
 **-[__NSArrayI dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75caf40
2013-09-17 10:26:48.774 iphoneApp[9395:2903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75caf40'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1cca012 0x1107e7e 0x1d554bd 0x1cb9bbc 0x1cb994e 0x26fc8ea 0x26fc97a 0x2027fa 0x35a2548 0x1c4df3f 0x1c4da39 0x1c70734 0x1c6ff44 0x1c6fe1b 0x35a1c50 0x9628f5b7 0x96279d4e)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception*
*emphasized text**
```

here is the code:

```
NSString *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *desc = [json valueForKey:@"description"];
NSLog(@"%@",desc);
[self.jobdescription loadHTMLString:desc baseURL:nil];
```

if I copy the output string from NSLog and put it in loadHTMLString its fine but if I put "desc" which is the same I will get the error. 
I have not idea what could have gone wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Check structure of data you get - from error message follows that value for key "description" is array, not string

Comment: but how is it possible. I am getting json data as string and save the value for key in NSString. I dont even have Array in there ? here is the value for key "description" that I get from nslog:"<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><strong>Arizona </strong><br /><strong>Academic Family Medicine</strong><br />One Million+ Metro Population<br /><br /></p><p>Our beautiful Southwest"

Comment: It is hard to say **why** without seeing all your code and all your data. Try to check what type desc object actually has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following statement.

```
[self.jobdescription loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",desc] baseURL:nil];
```

And please check whether the "self.jobdescription" is a UIWebView object or not.

Comment: Thanks Satya, it shows the String in the UIWebView but with parentheses and double quotes, is there any way I can eliminate them ?

Comment: Is it displaying those quotes & parentheses while directly loading with out using "desc" variable?

Comment: I just copied the code that you sent and it shows them !! also, Yakymiv says that desc might be an array. He is right. I change my code to:  NSString *desc = [json valueForKey:@"description"];
    NSString *myArrayString = [desc description];
        //NSLog(@"%@",myArrayString);
       // NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([myArrayString class]));
       [self.jobdescription loadHTMLString:myArrayString baseURL:nil];
it shows the string just fine but with parentheses !!!

Comment: then do this, replace the parentheses with empty strings. Like myArrayString = [myArrayString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""]; same for right parentheses also

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much. Here is my code for reference:NSString *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
      NSString *desc = [json valueForKey:@"description"];
      NSString *myArrayString = [desc description];
      NSString *myArrayString2 =  [[myArrayString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
     [self.jobdescription loadHTMLString:myArrayString2 baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `desc` is not string but array. Add `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([desc class]));` to ensure.

Comment: Yes seems like it is array. this is the out put: 2013-09-17 11:08:54.226 iphoneApp[9563:c07] __NSArrayI . what should I do then ?